# Взять число из поля для ввода и положить его в переменную на сайте

Tags: javascript

Есть поле для ввода (input). Из него нужно взять введенное число и положить в переменную для js файла. Как это сделать?

Comment: @Илья Химик2, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = document.getElementById('yourInputId').value;
```

Если подключен jquery, то

```
var value = $('#yourInputId').val();
```